# How to convert String, saved from localstorage, to Object from react-big-calendar

Tags: reactjs, date-fns, react-big-calendar

i tried to convert string from localstorage

```
{id: 0, title: "All Day Event very long title", allDay: true, start: "2021-11-29T16:00:00.000Z",…}
  allDay: true
  end: "2021-11-30T16:00:00.000Z"
  id: 0
  start: "2021-11-29T16:00:00.000Z"
  title: "All Day Event very long title"
```

to `event` object, like this:

```
{
    id: 0,
    title: 'All Day Event very long title',
    allDay: true,
    start: new Date(2021, 11, 0),
    end: new Date(2021, 11, 1),
  },
```

using the ff code I tried:
const [ allEvents, setAllEvents ] = useState(() => {

```
    const savedEvents = localStorage.getItem("events")

    if (savedEvents) {
        console.log("| parse: "+JSON.parse(savedEvents))
        return JSON.parse(savedEvents)
    } else {
        return events
    }
})

useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("events", JSON.stringify(allEvents))
}, [allEvents])
```

but the results shown in console will be `| parse: [object Object],` , how to convert start and end to `Date` object while retaining the title to string?

Comment: You're seeing `parse: [object Object]` because the result of `JSON.parse(savedEvents)` is being added to a string and the default `.toString()` for an object returns `[object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

You would need some additional function to convert your `start` and `end`. Something like this:

```js
const normalizeEvent = ({start, end, ...event}) => ({
  start: new Date(start),
  end: new Date(end),
  ..event
})

// ...

  const savedEvents = localStorage.getItem('events')

  if (savedEvents) {
    const storedEvents = JSON.parse(savedEvents)
    return storedEvents.map(normalizeEvent)
  }
```